# How to assign json response to a Array in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to angular 4 ,Here I need to consume API response and set it to the array .

but in my case it returns [object object].

JSON response Format:

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "S_NO": 1,
      "AN_ID": 37,
      "AN_TYPE": "Church",
      "AN_TITLE": "Donation",
      "AN_DATE": "2018-12-05T18:30:00",
      "AN_STATUS": "Active",
      "AN_DESC": "Test"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [
    {
      "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0914.JPG"
    },
    {
      "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0916.JPG"
    },
    {
      "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0917.JPG"
    },
    {
      "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0919.JPG"
    },
    {
      "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0921.JPG"
    }
  ]
}
```

app.component.html

```
for(var i = 0; i <= data; i++){
        this.urls.push(data['Table1'][0]['IMAGES']);
      }
```

But it returns [object object].Can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: Looks like your JSON structure is not what you are thinking of, could you post correct structure by typing manually?

Comment: It&#39;s easier if you console.log in the browser devtool since it looks the same as the image before

Comment: The Json Response in question is not actually a JSON. Can you please provide a proper JSON, or sample of whatever you are getting as the response

Comment: please check the updated post @Sachin Gupta

Comment: Updated post, you didn't show the whole structure where everything was wrapped in a Table1 object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data.Table1.forEach(image => this.urls.push(image.IMAGES));` to get the image URLs

Comment: url : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0914.JPG,http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0916.JPG,http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0917.JPG,http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0919.JPG,http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0921.JPG

Comment: It returns all the five urls and five times [object object]

Comment: Have you mapped the `data` object to any specific type? How are you accessing the `urls` ?

Comment: If it has the urls (the values from the data), it means that the solution i provided was working fine and the `urls` may have some data before pushing these values. Can you please verify the same.

Comment: Property 'Table1' does not exist on type 'Object'.

so I changed it to   data['Table1'].forEach(image => this.urls.push(image.IMAGES));

Answer (score 1):

It would be better if you used a code rather than an image, but probably it should be enough to use a `map` method.

```
const data = JSON.parse(`{"Table":[{"S_NO":1,"AN_ID":37,"AN_TYPE":"Church","AN_TITLE":"Donation","AN_DATE":"2018-12-05T18:30:00","AN_STATUS":"Active","AN_DESC":"Test"}],"Table1":[{"IMAGES":"http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0914.JPG"},{"IMAGES":"http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0916.JPG"},{"IMAGES":"http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0917.JPG"},{"IMAGES":"http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0919.JPG"},{"IMAGES":"http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0921.JPG"}]}`);

const urls = data.Table1.map(i => i.IMAGES)
```

Works like a charm and brings this back:

```
["http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0914.JPG", "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0916.JPG", "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0917.JPG", "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0919.JPG", "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0921.JPG"]
```

Comment: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'. @ Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted your data as a code, not as a image.

Comment: Can you update it once more and post actual JSON object?

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
this.urls.push(data.Table1[i].IMAGES);
```

In your loop

Comment: got the same url : [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] @Lucho

Comment: What you get from console.log(this.urls[0])?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test {
    public urls: string[] = [];
    public data: any = {
        "Table": [
            {
                "S_NO": 1,
                "AN_ID": 37,
                "AN_TYPE": "Church",
                "AN_TITLE": "Donation",
                "AN_DATE": "2018-12-05T18:30:00",
                "AN_STATUS": "Active",
                "AN_DESC": "Test"
            }
        ],
        "Table1": [
            { "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0914.JPG" },
            { "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0916.JPG" },
            { "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0917.JPG" },
            { "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0919.JPG" },
            { "IMAGES": "http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0921.JPG" }
        ]
    }

    constructor() {
        this.data.Table1.forEach((img: any) => this.urls.push(img.IMAGES));
    }
}

let t: Test = new Test();
console.log(JSON.stringify(t.urls));
```

Works like a charm for me:

```
Output > ["http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0914.JPG","http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0916.JPG","http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0917.JPG","http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0919.JPG","http://localhost:49813/Images/Announcements/Church/Donation/IMG_0921.JPG"]
```

you can test it : https://tsfiddle.tsmean.com/fiddle/MYer0EbO